# css or styling on @extend() , @section() can't work in one blade file, but in another blade it still working

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-blade

I can make sure my path is fine (because another blade file can running the css properly), i trying copy blade file to the problem blade but css still not working, trying to clear cache, change browser, and trying to change route but still not working

for extra information:

- Laravel Version : 10
- PHP Version : 8.1.9
- running cache clear using : php artisan optimize
- manually clear cache from Google Chrome browser
- trying to access it from Edge Browser
- i'm using Laragon to local server

this is my Controller

```
public function create()
{
    return view('pages.areaparkir.create');
}
```

this is my route:

```
Route::get('/area-parkir/create', [AreaParkirController::class, 'create'])->name('areaparkir.create');
```

this is my blade: (the file name is create.blade.php)

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <main role="main" class="main-content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <h2 class="page-title">Tambah Area Lab</h2>
                    <p class="text-muted">Tambah area lab agar dapat dipilih oleh user.</p>
                    <div class="card shadow mb-4">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <strong class="card-title">Area Lab Baru</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <form action="{{ route('lab.store') }}" method="post">
                                        @csrf
                                        <div class="form-group mb-3">
                                            <label for="simpleinput">Nama Lab</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="name" id="simpleinput" class="form-control">
                                        </div>
                                        <button type="submit" class="form-control bg-primary text-white">Simpan</button>
                                    </form>

                                </div> <!-- /.col -->

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div> <!-- / .card -->

                </div> <!-- .col-12 -->
            </div> <!-- .row -->
        </div> <!-- .container-fluid -->
        <div class="modal fade modal-notif modal-slide" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="defaultModalLabel"
            aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="defaultModalLabel">Notifications</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="list-group list-group-flush my-n3">
                            <div class="list-group-item bg-transparent">
                                <div class="row align-items-center">
                                    <div class="col-auto">
                                        <span class="fe fe-box fe-24"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <small><strong>Package has uploaded successfull</strong></small>
                                        <div class="my-0 text-muted small">Package is zipped and uploaded</div>
                                        <small class="badge badge-pill badge-light text-muted">1m ago</small>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="list-group-item bg-transparent">
                                <div class="row align-items-center">
                                    <div class="col-auto">
                                        <span class="fe fe-download fe-24"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <small><strong>Widgets are updated successfull</strong></small>
                                        <div class="my-0 text-muted small">Just create new layout Index, form, table</div>
                                        <small class="badge badge-pill badge-light text-muted">2m ago</small>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="list-group-item bg-transparent">
                                <div class="row align-items-center">
                                    <div class="col-auto">
                                        <span class="fe fe-inbox fe-24"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <small><strong>Notifications have been sent</strong></small>
                                        <div class="my-0 text-muted small">Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo</div>
                                        <small class="badge badge-pill badge-light text-muted">30m ago</small>
                                    </div>
                                </div> <!-- / .row -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="list-group-item bg-transparent">
                                <div class="row align-items-center">
                                    <div class="col-auto">
                                        <span class="fe fe-link fe-24"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <small><strong>Link was attached to menu</strong></small>
                                        <div class="my-0 text-muted small">New layout has been attached to the menu</div>
                                        <small class="badge badge-pill badge-light text-muted">1h ago</small>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div> <!-- / .row -->
                        </div> <!-- / .list-group -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block" data-dismiss="modal">Clear
                            All</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal fade modal-shortcut modal-slide" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="defaultModalLabel"
            aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="defaultModalLabel">Shortcuts</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body px-5">
                        <div class="row align-items-center">
                            <div class="col-6 text-center">
                                <div class="squircle bg-success justify-content-center">
                                    <i class="fe fe-cpu fe-32 align-self-center text-white"></i>
                                </div>
                                <p>Control area</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6 text-center">
                                <div class="squircle bg-primary justify-content-center">
                                    <i class="fe fe-activity fe-32 align-self-center text-white"></i>
                                </div>
                                <p>Activity</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row align-items-center">
                            <div class="col-6 text-center">
                                <div class="squircle bg-primary justify-content-center">
                                    <i class="fe fe-droplet fe-32 align-self-center text-white"></i>
                                </div>
                                <p>Droplet</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6 text-center">
                                <div class="squircle bg-primary justify-content-center">
                                    <i class="fe fe-upload-cloud fe-32 align-self-center text-white"></i>
                                </div>
                                <p>Upload</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row align-items-center">
                            <div class="col-6 text-center">
                                <div class="squircle bg-primary justify-content-center">
                                    <i class="fe fe-users fe-32 align-self-center text-white"></i>
                                </div>
                                <p>Users</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6 text-center">
                                <div class="squircle bg-primary justify-content-center">
                                    <i class="fe fe-settings fe-32 align-self-center text-white"></i>
                                </div>
                                <p>Settings</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main> <!-- main -->
@endsection
```

this is my folder path:

[image]

this is my eror when running it on browser (the css is not load)

[image]

i can make sure my folder path is not the problem because in another blade the css working properly (the red box is the button to direct to the create.blade.php

[image]

the code from that red box below

```
<div class="col ml-auto">
    <div class="dropdown float-right">
        <a href="{{ route('areaparkir.create') }}">
        <button class="btn btn-primary float-right ml-3" type="button">
                                                        Tambah Area
                                                        Parkir +
        </button></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

sorry for bad english

Comment: Once again, please double-check the CSS path by inspecting the elements tab in your browser.

Comment: you are not showing the part of the layout that includes the CSS ... most likely you just have a relative path instead of an absolute path

Comment: yeah @lagbox my css is not loaded, because other blade is not appear this problem... so i not expect the problem in my css loaded problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

after paying close attention to detail, changing controller in route, many times clear cache, the problem is my code is not loaded the css

this is my code before, you can see my app-light.css is not loaded using asset()
[image]

this is my code after loaded the css using asset()
[image]

i still not understand, why in other blade file the css is load as i show you in my question above..... but only in this file (create.blade.php) the css is not loaded....

i'm trying to not loaded the app-light.css again and when i tried to access the other blade... it still running! after clear cache, change browser it still running

you can see, i disabled the code using comment
[image]

and when i tried access it on my browser, the problem is not appear

[image]

even i tried access it using other browser (edge) the problem is not appear

[image]

anyone have argument about my problem?